# How to echo a variable in an array?

Tags: php

Is it possible to echo a variable in an array? Imm trying to create CSS via PHP:

```
class headerStyle{
    // now  creating our CONSTRUCTOR function
    function __construct($args=array()) {
        $this->fields = array('background','color','fontSize','backgroundUrl','imagePosition','Width','Height','backgroundSize','margin','padding','backgroundRepeat');
        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            $this->{"$field"} = $args["$field"];
        }
    }
}


$value = $_POST['mainHeaderBg'];

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600); 
$var=($_COOKIE["TestCookie"]);
$style = new headerStyle(
       array(
         'background'=>echo $var,
         'color'=>"#F5F3F4",
         'fontSize'=>"24px",
         //backgroundUrl=>"_images/bodyBg1.jpg",
         'backgroundSize'=>"50% 50%",
         'padding'=>"10px 0px 0px 0px",
         'margin'=>"0px 0px 0px 0px",
         'width'=>"100%",
         'height'=>"60px",
         'imagePosition'=>"top-left",
       )
);
```

I need to pass a dynamic variable so that it can display in index. I'm unable to echo a variable in an array.

Comment: Do you mean you just want `'background' => $var,`?

Comment: No,All style now just trying for background-color

Answer (score 1):

You should change `background'=>echo $var` to `'background'=> $var`

Comment: I tried even that is not working.

Comment: Can you update the question with your its html code?

Comment: I'm trying to create dynamic CSS via PHP,when i give direct values its working fine but when i pass variable its not working because page get refresh and an trying ti store that in a cookie and then use that in an array..Is it possible to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree with other users that this line need correction

```
'background'=>echo $var,
```

Back to debugging,

to get the array content for debugging purpose, put this line anywhere you want to check the array content. It's better to view the result in "view source" mode (like in firefox view source)

```
print_r($yourArray);
```